# Solving recurance relation with master theorem

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I'm studying asymotic analysis and i encounter this problem:

Given a recurance relation: $$T(n)= aT(n/b)+cn^a (n>0;a>=1;b>=1)$$
prove that
if $a>a^b$ then Tn=$\mathfrak\theta(n^{log_b(a)})$
if $a=a^b$ then Tn=$\mathfrak\theta(n^alog(n))$
if $a<a^b$ then Tn=$\mathfrak\theta(n^a)$

This problem scream master theorem to me but i can't seem to solve it to be exact i can't find the relation between $n^a$ and $n^{log_b(a)}$  i have also tried out subsitution and it did'nt work out.